# Keep user in Real Time of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website without too much interaction. It is a video player, playing videos for some hours. My problem is that this page does not have scrolling or clicking interaction, and then Real Time of Google Analytics "loses" my user after a while.

Is there any option to keep this user on Real Time counting of GA?

Comment: I would create a timer on the page and send some event to Google every 30 seconds or so:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: Yes, that's perfect! I didn't realize that GA has an option that does not affects the pageviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good idea to extend users activity in realtime view by adding lots of hits. These will skew you site's statistics. What you should do is extend the session timeout to longer than your longest video. The max is 4.5 hours. If the videos are longer you might want to send a non interaction hit abit before the session time's out. The format for such an [event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) for universal analytics is:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {'nonInteraction': 1});
```

To set the ime out look under Admin > .js tracking Info > Session Settings.

Comment: Your code was exactly what I was looking for! Worked perfect for me! Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. i use gtag with the correct code gtag('event'...
I can see the events beeing sent to GA, but the user will disappear from the "Real time" count after a few minutes (less than the time specified in the tracking code settings)

Comment: seems to be working, but only without the "non_interaction" setting. But i need to send the event frequently. Not sure if the 500 event limit still apply with gtag